# Cannot connect action to static UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am unable to link an action to a static `UITableViewCell` that was designed in Interface Builder. I have `TableViewController` (as a `UITableViewController`) that is the data source and delegate of the `tableView`. The method I am trying to connect is below:

```
@IBAction func openWebsite(AnyObject) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://google.co.uk")!)
}
```

I have tried dragging the action from the Inspector but it will not apply itself to the `UITableViewCell`. I have also done the reverse and tried to drag a connection from Interface Builder to `TableViewController` in which it will only connect as an outlet and not an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for static cells I would recommend you to add the delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and then respond to that action, due to the fact it can be tricky to setup actions for such cells. There are many underlying views for UITableView cell and adding action to some of them can be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Two things can be done:

1. Change the method declaration to following and drag :

   @IBAction func openWebsite(sender: AnyObject) {
       UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://google.co.uk")!) // was missing param name
   }
2. When you drag and drop the action to the controller, change IBOutlet to IBAction from the popup menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use the index of the cell, then call your function from that.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print(indexPath.section)
    print(indexPath.row)

    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        // call function here
        openWebsite()
    }

}
```